# getResourceAsStream returning null with TagSupport

Tags: java, jsp, tags

I've got a class file extending the TagSupport, here I want to read a property file, but it is not working. I think getResourceAsStream is returning null.

i am using exploded war files on bith systems.

Code:

> public class MyTag extends TagSupport {
>
> ```
>   private int getUsers() {
>
>   ServletContext servletContext = pageContext.getServletContext();
>
>   InputStream in = pageContext.getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/app.properties");
>
>   Properties properties = new Properties();
>   properties.load(in);
>   int users= Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty("users"));
>
>   return users;    }
> ```
>
> }

This code works on my pc, but doesnt work the test system. I get the following exception:

> java.lang.NullPointerException ERROR [STDERR]     at
>   java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Properties.java:418) ERROR
>   [STDERR]          at java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:337)
>   ERROR [STDERR]    at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:325)

Answer (score 1):

Why does your `app.properties` reside in `/WEB-INF`? If it would've been `/WEB-INF/classes`, you could simply call `getResourceAsStream("/app.properties")`. This is because the argument to [`getResourceAsStream(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) is resolved relative to the classpath.

Comment: that is another thing, I think. But why does it work on dev system and not on test?

Comment: Hard to say without knowing anything about either system (OS, JDK version, application server, etc.). But generally speaking, property files and other resources are placed in `/WEB-INF/classes`.

Comment: Thanks. So is there anything wrong with my code. With getServletContext, it allows you to load resources relative to the context root.